# MySQL Connector/Net 6.0.2 path not found

Tags: c#, mysql

I created a Windows form application (C#) with Mysql as back end

mysql connector net 6 0 2 is used in my form for connection

the exe works fine on my system but when i copied it to other computer and try to run it, it is giving me eror as 
MySQL Connector/Net   6.0.2 file path not found

Thanx

Comment: So did the other computer have the MySQL connector installed, and the same version that you've linked against ? Or did you copy over the MySQL dlls ?

Comment: the other computer have different version of my sql connector. So, Do i need to first install "mysql connector net 6 0 2" on each computer where I intended to use this EXE. I have no idea where to copy MySQL dlls? thanx

Comment: Yes, or you need to copy the .dlls from your machine and e.g. place them alongside the .exe (You can right click the mysql reference in your solution and set it to Copy to local to place the .dll in the .exe output directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to deploy the MySQL Connector assemblies with your own application (or merge them into your own application assembly), or ensure the connector is installed on the machine you need to run the application on.

Comment: sorry to ask silly question but how to deploy the MySQL Connector assemblies with application? Can I just copy "MySql.Data.dll" on the other computer also ?

Comment: The easiest way is to make an installer to deploy all the files you need at once. Add a Visual Studio setup project to your solution and take it from there, or look into using ClickOnce.

Answer (score 0):

Try packing your application in a installer and add the connector as a resource when setting the project .Net makes this really easy but differs based on the IDE you are using.